# Install pgpool from RPM

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pgpool

I am installing pgpool-II on rhel 7. I want to install pgpool-II using RPM package for postgreSQL 9.2.

pgpool docs have below line mentioned

```
yum install pgpool-II-pg96
pg96 means PostgreSQL 9.5.
```

Does it mean **pgpool-II-pg93** means pgpool for postgresql-9.2?

Also, i didnt find any package like **pgpool-II-pg92**

Comment: I would assume its a typo. I know 3.4 could not work with postgres 9.5, while 3.5 could. but eg  3.7 can work with both 9.6 and 10 - so logic is not minor release minus one :) btw pgpool docs have multiple typos

Comment: ok got it. btw how can I install pgpool using rpm for PostgreSQL-9.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the oldest release supporting Postgres 9.2 seems to be 3.4.
Try one for your distro, eg for rhel-6-x86_64 here:

http://www.pgpool.net/yum/rpms/3.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/

Comment: I have one more question,  do we need to setup pgppol on both master and slave?

Comment: mnah... if you aim to use `pgpool_recover` extension, you will need library and thus yes - you need it on every host you want to use in HA setup. but if you use it for load balancing or pooling - no, I would not say you need it on slaves

Comment: What are other alternates of Virtual IP that can be used so that we don't have to change connection strings after failover? Is there any tool for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can install pgpool II for Postgresql 9.2 from link

https://www.pgpool.net/yum/rpms/3.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgpool-II-pg92-3.4.8-1pgdg.rhel6.x86_64.rpm